# ios to logout user automatcally after selected time interval from the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, objective-c-blocks

In My App, whenever a user keeps an app idle for more than 15 mins my app logs the user out form the app.This work perfectly for me.
And again when user tries to login he is able to do that.

But the problem is, let say if I am logged on into the app & I have kept my app idle for 15  mins, I receive an error message and my app makes me logout.

I still have the error message populated on the screen, I haven't closes that message and again I have kept my app idle for another 15 mins.

Now when I close the error message and again try to login into the app it doesn't allow me.

It always gives a message as "Error - Generic error message".

Following is my code:
I have created an UIApplication class

```
@interface PSATimerUIApplication : UIApplication
{

NSTimer *_idleTimer;

}

-(void)resetIdleTimer;


@implementation PSATimerUIApplication


- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
     [super sendEvent:event];

     // Fire up the timer upon first event

    if(!_idleTimer) 
    {
         [self resetIdleTimer];
    }

    // Check to see if there was a touch event

   NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];       

  if ([allTouches count] > 0){
      UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;

      if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan){

           [self resetIdleTimer];
      }
  }
}

-(void)resetIdleTimer{ 
    if (_idleTimer) {
        [_idleTimer invalidate];
    }

   // Schedule a timer to fire in kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes

  int timeout = PSAApplicationTimeoutInMinutes * 60;

  _idleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeout target:self selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void)idleTimerExceeded {
   /*Post a notification so anyone who subscribes to it can be notified when
   *the application times out */

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:PSAApplicationDidTimeoutNotification object:nil];
}
```

had also updated the main Function:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
     @autoreleasepool 
     {
         return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([PSATimerUIApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([PSAAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Can any one help me out with this?
I am using AFTNetworking1.0 for all my http calls.

Answer (score 0):

after 15 mins if app get idle the app automatically idle. Releases all its temporary memory data. so, you prevent to app idle(from setting) after 15 min or do it before 15 mins.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a UserDefaults variable and use it as a flag.
When the user is logged in and active, set it to true. 
if user logged out or timed out, set the variable to false.
And in the viewDidAppear and viewDidLoad of the class check whether the flag is false. if yes, then pop the login view controller. else continue.